# Swift: remove background color when button clicked

Tags: ios, user-interface, swift

I created a button and when it is clicked, it's background image changes. However the issue is when I click it , it gives a rectangle with a color.

*Image*:

[image]

*Should Be*:

[image]

I don't want to see that clicking background.

My codes are below:

```
let on = UIImage(named: "on") as UIImage
let off = UIImage(named: "off") as UIImage

btn.setBackgroundImage(off, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: Check that button type is Custom or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use Storyboard buttons which is `IBOutlet UIButton` object. By default it is not set as a custom type. So if you set background of this button as an image, It shows border of that button with the image.

**For Storyboard variables:**

1. Select `UIButton` control in Storyboard. Go to **Attribute Inspector** > Change type **System** to **Custom**

See the reference images

[image]

[image]

**For programmatically created buttons:**

If you create `UIButton` object programmatically than set button type as `UIButtonTypeCustom`.

Objective C Code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Swift Code:

```
var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
```

Answer (score 3):

just use this

```
btn.setBackgroundImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
```